# Getting and using the value from text box

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a text box in my google script where the user enters their name.

Later on down the script, I create a spreadsheet with the date, but I also want to use their name they entered in the text box as part of the file name.

Here is where I ask for the name:

```js
var userRequestTB = app.createTextBox().setName('userName');
```

And this is where I want to insert the value of the text box into the file name:

```js
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.create('USERNAME FROM TEXTBOX'+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), 'ddMMMyyyy'));
```

Trouble is, I don't know the code to use the value stored in the text box.

Comment: if the name attribute of the textbox is userName then it would be.

document.getElementsByName('userName')[0].value;

If you have an id to the textbox it would be 

document.getElementById('userName').value;

Comment: Is that a standalone app or is it embedded in a sheet?  Could you show more of the script please?  As it is wè can't answer accurately.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out.  Everything was defined in a previous function:

```
var userRequestTB = app.createTextBox().setId('userName').setName('userName');
```

So in the new function where I wanted to use the value from userName

I inserted:

```
var userName = e.parameter.userName;
```

and then where I wanted to use the value, I just used the variable name.

Not sure if this was the correct to do it, but it worked so I am happy.

Answer (score 0):

if the name attribute of the textbox is userName then it would be.

```
document.getElementsByName('userName')[0].value;
```

If you have an id to the textbox it would be

```
document.getElementById('userName').value;
```

Comment: This is not how it works in UiApp.This question is clearly using UiAppservice.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar that is setup to name the file with the date that is typed in the box.

This might help you.

```
  destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var name = Browser.inputBox('Enter Week Ending Date ONLY', 'Example:     11-5-14 \\n\\n', Browser.Buttons.OK);   

   destination.rename("FraminghamWE" + name); //name will copy whatever is typed in to the message box

   costReport.getRange('D20').setValue(name); // here I also set that date on one of my 
                                              //other sheets that requires this weeks ending date.
```